# hyper : implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm trying to refactor code by moving the hyper server out of main and allow the struct function to accept a function as below:

```
// main.rs
#[tokio::main]
async fn main()  {
    let listener = Listener::new(String::from("127.0.0.1"), String::from("3000"));
    listener.start(request_handler);
}

async fn request_handler(req: Request<Body>) -> ConfigResult<Response<Body>> {
    match req.method() {
        &Method::GET => get(req.body()),
         _ => Ok(Response::builder()
                .status(StatusCode::NOT_FOUND)
                .body("NOT FOUND".into())
                .unwrap())
    }
}
```

```
// lib.rs

pub type ConfigError = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>;
pub type ConfigResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>;


#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Listener(pub SocketAddr);

impl<'a> Listener {
    pub fn new(addr: String, port:String) -> Self {
        let ip = IpAddr::from_str(addr.as_str()).unwrap();
        let address =  SocketAddr::new(ip, port.parse::<u16>().unwrap());
        Listener(address)
    }

    pub async fn start<F>(&'a self, request_handler: F ) -> ConfigResult<()>
        where F: Fn(Request<Body>) -> ConfigResult<Response<Body>> + Sync + 'a
    {
        let mut service_closure = move |req| {
            async {
                request_handler(req)
            }
        };

        let mut make_service_closure = move |_| {
            async {
                Ok::<_, ConfigError>(service_fn(&service_closure))
            }
        };
        let service = make_service_fn(make_service_closure);
        let server = Server::bind(&self.0).serve(service);
        server.await?;
        Ok(())
    }

}
```

Im getting the error:

```
error: implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
  --> src/config/server.rs:36:15
   |
36 |         server.await?;
   |               ^^^^^^ implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough
   |
   = note: closure with signature `fn(&'2 AddrStream) -> impl Future<Output = Result<hyper::service::util::ServiceFn<&[closure@src/config/serva.rs:23:35: 27:10], Body>, Box<dyn StdError + Send + Sync>>>` must implement `FnOnce<(&'1 AddrStream,)>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
   = note: ...but it actually implements `FnOnce<(&'2 AddrStream,)>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

Looking at the error above, my conclusion is its a lifetime error, where `let make_service_closure = move |_| {...}` requires lifetime of '1 but when i try `let make_service_closure = move | a: &'a AddrStream| {...}` i get lifetime mismatch error

```
expected type `for<'r> FnMut<(&'r AddrStream,)>`
               found type `FnMut<(&'a AddrStream,)>`
```

plus the error implementation of `FnOnce` is not general enough. Please help understand which lifetime should i use for the hyper service function and why is `FnOnce` is not general enough.

Comment: It's hard to say without a full example we can compile ourselves. I suspect the problem is `'a` in `where F: Fn(Request<Body>) -> ConfigResult<Response<Body>> + Sync + 'a` -- try `'static` there instead.

Comment: i tried `F: Fn(Request<Body>) -> ConfigResult<Response<Body>> + Sync + Send + 'static` but i get ` borrowed value does not live long enough` for both ` request_handler` and `service_closure`

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that's part of the return value from the closure, not the closure itself. Regardless, this is going to be hard to debug without an example we can compile ourselves. There is too much missing from the code you have posted.

Comment: added more code.

Comment: We still need more. Rust doesn't know what any of these types are, because there's no `Cargo.toml` we can draw from, nor any `use` directives.

Comment: @cdhowie https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=306d62a5c48679c2d71fe50d812d7c13 (I shouldn't have done this, I know).

Comment: One issue I just discovered is that `F` in `Listener::start()` describes a sync closure, but you pass an async function, which returns `impl Future`. You need to say something like `pub async fn start<F, Fut>(...) where F: Fn(Request<Body>) -> Fut, Fut: Future<Output=ConfigResult<Response<Body>>> + Sync + 'a`, Not exactly sure about the lifetimes (maybe `'a` needs to belong to `F` and not `Fut`).